# Parse input from string containing ints

Tags: java

I am trying to get input from a string containing ints. So when a user types in the command "getrange(1,12)" I need to read the inital command as a string, and the two numbers inside it as an ints. I was thinking I could do a number of Splits() but I think that might get messy. In addition Split() keeps them as strings I think.

My ultimate goal is to write an IF statement like this:

```
if("getrange")
{

    while(1 <= 12)
    {
        output.println(MyArray[1])
        1++
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?
I know this is pretty crude, let me know if I need to clarify. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String input = "getrange(1,12)";
String[] parts = input.split("\\(");
System.out.println("Command: " + parts[0]);
String[] argsParts = parts[1].substring(0, parts[1].indexOf(")")).split(",");
int arg1 = Integer.parseInt(argsParts[0].trim());
int arg2 = Integer.parseInt(argsParts[1].trim());        
System.out.println("Args: " + arg1 + ", " + arg2);
```

Output:

```
Command: getrange
Args: 1, 12
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
 s.findInLine("getRange\((\\d+),(\\d+)\)");
 MatchResult result = s.match();
 //You should do some error checking here (are there enough matches ...)
 int StartRange == Integer.parseInt(result.group(0));
 int EndRange == Integer.parseInt(result.group(1));
```

And you can take it from there :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to get the numbers and then then do an Integer.parseInt() on the two pieces.  The other option which is less ideal would be to do a combo of substring and split to remove the unwanted characters.